# Custom keyword color in Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, syntax-highlighting

When there is a lot of code I would find it easier to get an idea of the structure of a program if keywords like `new`, `null`, `true`, `int` etc would have different colors than keywords that actually are responsible for structure like `if`, `while` etc.

Is it possible to color have custom colors for certain keywords? For example change the color of `new` and `true` in this picture?

[image: Illustration of problem]

Answer (score 5):

No, it's not possible to change the color of certain keywords, other than by writing a plugin.

Comment: I have found that you can create your own File Type and set keywords there. But this unfortunately breaks a lot of the functionality Intellij offers and editing the File Type Java doesn't work. So I guess you're right.